# Uploading image to nodejs api to store in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I have a user model for mongoDB. below is the model. As you can see there is a Buffer type in which I have to store an image.  How can I write a route to add a user with all the details below including the image. The image won't be higher than 5mb. Also I need to know how to test it in post man.

```
const userSchema = new db.mongoose.Schema ({
  name  : String,
  phoneNumber : String,
  Email : String,
  password  : String,
  CreatedDate : {type: Date, default : Date.now()},
  Proof       : Buffer,
  TotalOrder  : {type : Number, default: 0},
  TotalSales  : {type : Number, default: 0},
  isAdmin     : { type  : Boolean, default  : false },
});
```

Comment: Detailing the whole approach to store and test an image is not desirable in a StackOverflow answer. You are more likely to get help if you mention what did you try and didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Stackoverflow** is not the place where you can expect others to do the job of you. So, here I'm just pointing out (not limited to) what you need to upload a file:

1. [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), a node.js middleware, you can learn [here](https://medium.com/@SigniorGratiano/image-uploads-with-multer-f306469ef2) how to upload an image using multer
2. You will need [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) for accessing the file system. Read the docs.

If you know how to Design API with any library like (*Express*), by using the above two technology you may succed.